# error interpreting jpeg image file (not a jpeg file starts with 0x27 0x5f) it is only an error in the default image viewer in lubuntu 16.10

Tags: gnome, lubuntu, 16.10, eog, image-viewers

This happens every time I try opening an image from any ftp server and even though the image opens perfectly on Firefox or vlc media player or any other image viewer but whenever I open it in the default image viewer in lubuntu it doesn't work. Updating eog did help though. I've attached an image of the default image viewer malfunctioning and the updated image viewer opening the same file over LAN. It should be noted that it isn't a problem with the file because I can open it after copying it. The problem here was that these are two distinct applications: gpicview and eog but both of these image viewers are labled as "image viewer" in the applications menu and they share the exact same icon but they are categorised differently because the old one was in accessories and the newer one is in graphics which is why I was able to distinguish between these two otherwise the difference can only be spotted in the properties or by running the program to find out which is which. Waiting for the description/purpose show up while hovering on the shortcut in the applications menu can also help.
I'm gonna attach a screenshot explaining this from the device I was using.

[In this screenshot you can see the file properties of the shortcuts and how similar they appear to be on the outside because they have the same name and icon (the new one can be seen next to the Adobe reader knockoff) . I was only able to distinguish them because the old one: gpicview is in accessories and the new one: eog is categorised under graphics in the application menu. You can also see that it says "view your images easily" when I hover on the old one in application menu but with the new one it says "view and rotate images" instead and they have different names in the file properties of course because the similarities are mostly in the shortcuts and not the actual applications.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qK2wD.jpg)
Sometimes an update can be so drastic that it doesn't replace the older version but that doesn't seem to be the case here. Something similar had happened when I'd updated Firefox on windows. Recently I had downloaded a newer version of Firefox for lubuntu and I didn't get .Deb package instead it was a.tar.bz2 archive so I extracted it and ran it from there but the default shortcut in the applications menu was somehow linked to this extracted folder in my downloads and it went back to the older version after I had deleted that folder. I had edited this post without all of this irrelevant stuff a moment ago but then my browser crashed before I could save it an autosave feature would really help in such situations.

I was unable to provide an update for so many months because I was trying to figure out how to boot that device up without using the keyboard which is why I'm typing this in with a cellphone but that's a separate topic.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: So, an update to Eye-of-Gnome fixed the issue. What's your question? Or is this merely a bug report?

Comment: Well David even after the update it only works when I drag and drop the image onto the image viewer but when I double click on it the error that you can see in the background of this image pops up same as before. Its almost like the older version is still there and it is being used instead of the updated image viewer upon double clicking and I'm fine with it. It's actually nice being able to chose between both versions they're really different. In fact I wish it were possible to do that with every update 'cause then you'll be able to switch back and forth without adding and removing anything.

Comment: What’s the default image viewer for your user account? Which image viewer comes up when you open a JPEG file stored on your local drives? What’s the output of `mimeopen [JPEG-FILE]`? What’s your Ubuntu release?

Comment: Also, could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidFoerster thanks for pointing that out I'm gonna do that now and I'm sorry for the delayed response.

Comment: @DavidFoerster `mimeopen [JPEG-FILE]
The program 'mimeopen' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install libfile-mimeinfo-perl`

Comment: @DavidFoerster so apparently I don't have mimeopen installed. I had to edit the last comment because I had used an inverted comma instead of a back-tick. Is it necessary to mention your username or do you get notified either way? The older image viewer is gpicview and it  opens the images on my local drives. The newer one is called eog and it was installed after I had installed Eye-of-gnome. It was never installed by default so it did not replace the gpicview. It had the same name and icon so I thought it had been replaced. I'm gonna add the same info in my question by editing it.

Comment: @DavidFoerster `$ mimeopen [JPEG-FILE]
Could not determine mimetype for file: [JPEG-FILE]`

Comment: @DavidFoerster That was quick! I had install two of its dependecies. Why can't they put all of them in a single package? I also came across a mirror.in.th/ubuntu while trying to download three of those .deb packages so I clicked on it assuming it was Indian but it wasn't functional and it turns out (in.th) that's actually a TLD for Thailand. So now I'm gonna do that with a JPEG on a phone via FTP to see what I'll get and you'll find the result in my next comment.

Comment: `gvfs/ftp:host=192.168.1.34,port=3721/DCIM/Camera$ mimeopen [IMG_20170519_164455]
Could not determine mimetype for file: [IMG_20170519_164455]
lubuntu@lubuntu:/run/user/999/gvfs/ftp:host=192.168.1.34,port=3721/DCIM/Camera$ mimeopen [IMG_20170519_164455.jpg]
Could not determine mimetype for file: [IMG_20170519_164455.jpg]
lubuntu@lubuntu:/run/user/999/gvfs/ftp:host=192.168.1.34,port=3721/DCIM/Camera$  `

Comment: @DavidFoerster `$ mimeopen /run/user/999/gvfs/ftp:host=192.168.1.34,port=3721/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20170519_164455.jpg
Please choose a default application for files of type image/jpeg

 1) mtPaint graphic editor  (mtpaint)
 2) Image Viewer  (gpicview)
 3) Firefox Web Browser  (firefox)
 4) Feh  (feh)
 5) ImageMagick (display Q16)  (display-im6.q16)
 6) ImageMagick (display Q16)  (display-im6)
 7) Ristretto Image Viewer  (ristretto)
 8) Image Viewer  (eog)
 9) Other...

use application #
`

Comment: Seems like I finally got it right but it seems like I have to choose something here now.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I keep getting these suggestions to "move this discussion to chat" am I supposed to do that?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Did you notice how gpicview and eog have the same lable even here in this list?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like no default application was set to open JPEG files. Could you please do so either via the system settings, the file manager context menu, or `mimeopen -d [JPEG-FILE]` and try again?